# How to check validation of Aadhar card, driving license and Pan Card, Bank account number, IFS CODE, UPI Id in Flutter programmatically

Tags: flutter, validation, dart

How to make common method for checking all the validation in single code for various strings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The fastest and easiest solution is to use a regex expression:**

```
extension AadharNumberValidator on String {
  bool isValidAadharNumber() {
    return RegExp(
            r'^[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{4}$')
        .hasMatch(this);
  }
}

extension PanCardValidator on String {
  bool isValidPanCardNo() {
    return RegExp(
            r'^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}$')
        .hasMatch(this);
  }
}

extension DrivingLicense Validator on String {
  bool isValidLicenseNo() {
    return RegExp(
            r'^(([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2})( )|([A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}))((19|20)[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{7}$')
        .hasMatch(this);
  }
}
```

**And use an extension of String for validate**

```
TextFormField(
  autovalidate: true,
  validator: (input) => input.isValidAadharNumber() ? null : "Check your aadhar number",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String validateAccountNumber(String value) {
  String pattern = '[0-9]{9,18}';
  RegExp regExp = RegExp(pattern);
  if (value.isEmpty) {
    return 'Please Enter Account Number';
  } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
    return 'Please Enter Valid Account Number';
  }
  return "";
}

String validateUpiID(String value) {
  String pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{2,256}@[a-zA-Z]{2,64}';
  RegExp regExp = RegExp(pattern);
  if (value.isEmpty) {
    return 'Please Enter UPI ID';
  } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
    return 'Please Enter valid UPI ID';
  }
  return "";
}

String validateIFSC(String value) {
  String pattern = '^[A-Z]{4}0[A-Z0-9]{6}\$';
  RegExp regExp = RegExp(pattern);
  if (value.isEmpty) {
    return 'Please Enter IFSC';
  } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
    return 'Please Enter valid IFSC';
  }
  return "";

  // It should be 11 characters long.
  // The first four characters should be upper case alphabets.
  // The fifth character should be 0.
  // The last six characters usually numeric, but can also be alphabetic.
}

String validateAadharcard(String value) {
  String pattern = r'^[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{4}$';
  RegExp regExp = RegExp(pattern);
  if (value.isEmpty) {
    return 'Please Enter Aadhar card Number';
  } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
    return 'Please Enter Valid Aadhar card Number';
  }
  return "";
}

String validatePancard(String value) {
  String pattern = r'^[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}$';
  RegExp regExp = RegExp(pattern);
  if (value.isEmpty) {
    return 'Please Enter Pancard Number';
  } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
    return 'Please Enter Valid Pancard Number';
  }
  return "";
}

String validateDrivingLicense(String value) {
  String pattern =
      r'^(([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2})( )|([A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}))((19|20)[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{7}$';
  RegExp regExp = RegExp(pattern);
  if (value.isEmpty) {
    return 'Please Enter DrivingLicense ID';
  } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
    return 'Please Enter Valid DrivingLicense ID';
  }
  return "";
}

Use String validation like, 

 if (validateIFSC(
                                              controller.ifscTxt.value.text)
                                              .isNotEmpty) {
                                            printData("IFSC code", controller.ifscTxt.value.text.toString());
                                            snackBar(
                                                context,
                                                validateIFSC(controller
                                                    .ifscTxt.value.text));
                                            return;
                                          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to validate all types of patterns. Like Pancard has pattern like ABCDE111F. Aadhar card is just 12 digit number and so on.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).